# How can I do pre checking ... before executing a function in the Python?

Tags: python

I have functions in which I am doing database operations. I want to do something special,before trying to fetch data from database, I want to check whether cursor object is null and whether connection is dropped due to time out. How can I do pre checking in the Python ?

my functions, foo, bar :

```
 Class A:
   connect = None
   cursor = None

   def connect(self)
      self.connect = MySQLdb.connect ( ... )
      self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()
   def foo (self) :
       self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM car_models");
   def bar (self) :
       self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM incomes");
```

Comment: on a sidenote: how do you distinguish A.connect method from A.connect property? I see some ambiguity in this code.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with checking before an operation is that the bad condition you're checking for could happen between the check and the operation.

For example, suppose you had a method `is_timed_out()` to check if the connection had timed out:

```
if not self.cursor.is_timed_out():
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM incomes")
```

On the face of it, this looks like you've avoided the possibility of a CursorTimedOut exception from the execute call.  But it's possible for you to call is_timed_out, get a False back, then the cursor times out, and then you call the execute function, and get an exception.

Yes, the chance is very small that it will happen at just the right moment.  But in a server environment, a one-in-a-million chance will happen a few times a day.  Bad stuff.

You have to be prepared for your operations to fail with exceptions.  And once you've got exception handling in place for those problems, you don't need the pre-checks any more, because they are redundant.

Comment: Or as Gordon Letwin put it: "One in a million is next Tuesday" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the cursor is null easily:

```
if cursor is None:
     ... do something ...
```

Otherwise the usual thing in Python is to "ask for forgiveness not permission": use your database connection and if it has timed out catch the exception and handle it (otherwise you might just find that it times out between your test and the point where you use it).

Comment: I feel there should be much more smarter way to do same thing what you have wrote. Thanks